# jQuery mobile page navigation behaviour

Tags: jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I have a very simple .NET MVC3 project set up using jquery mobile for rendering to mobile devices.

I have one page...

```
www.mydomain.com/landingpage
```

and on this page I have a link to another page:

```
www.mydomain.com/homepage
```

My problem is this, the link from landing page works fine - loads, animates and returns the content correctly.

However once on the homepage, all the homepage links no longer work. Homepage contains about 3 different jquery mobile "pages" and trying to link to them is not working. This is due to the hash format, it's still showing something similar to:

```
www.mydomain.com/landingpage#homepage
```

So when link is generated it looks something like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/landingpage#homepage
```

Then when I link to one of the other pages similar to this:

```
a href="#homepage2">Homepage 2</a>
```

Clicking the link takes the user back to the initial landing page and updates the URL to something similar to:

```
www.mydomain.com/landingpage#homepage2
```

But I'm fairly sure it should look more something like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/homepage#homepage2
```

I can get it working correctly by using rel="external" on the first link but I'd like to avoid this as it reloads the page and you lose page transition animation etc.

Any ideas much appreciated :)

Comment: which version of jqm are you using?

Comment: so basically you have two separate files. landingpage.aspx homepage.aspx?
in the mean time let me work out a example for you.

Comment: hmmm. after testing out myself.  I found out from homepage --> homepage2(in same html) will not have any issue.
I problem only occur when i do this.
landingpage --> homepage --> homepage2
I'm guessing something's wrong when going to homepage from landingPage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone stuck with same problem, this fixed it for me:

I manually set the **data-url** attribute on each jQuery mobile "page" element (the div with data-role="page"). In turn, this forced a refresh of the URL hash of the pages when doing post-backs.

Not sure of the exact cause but I have a feeling because it is posting back to the same page but server is returning a different page, the URL hash gets a bit confused.

So just manually set the **data-url** attribute correctly and when the page posts back and the next page is loaded, correct URL hash will be updated.

So for example:

```
<div data-role="page" id="pageId" data-url="/Page/URL/Here/">
```

Little bit tricky to explain so if anyone needs a bit of help feel free to contact me directly! RC2 has been released since I initially posted this so I'm also unsure of what changes are included.

Answer (score 1):

On your landing page set rel="external" on the link to the homepage. This will disable the animation however the ajax navigation on the homepage will work properly.

Comment: Yes I can get the navigation to function correctly using this method however what I'm wanting to know is if there is a way I can link to a different page on the same domain using the same ajax implementation so animations etc are maintained. I can get the link to work however once the other page loads, ajax links on this page no longer function correctly. so far doesn't sound like it's possible, thanks for your reply though.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a problem when you load a external page.
When you try load a external page and from there you try to load a internal page, jquery mobile will assume the internal page you're loading is already in the DOM while it's not simply because 
when you load a external page with multiple  only the first 1 get loaded thus the internal page you try to link to does not exist.

And the reason why you get this

```
www.mydomain.com/landingpage#homepage2
```

and not this

```
www.mydomain.com/homepage#homepage2
```

is because landingpage is the FIRST page loaded. subsequence pages is all loaded into the DOM so jqm assume the  is already in the DOM so it try to load.

currently i believe the only work around is not to place multiple jqm page in a file and load them as a external file.

e.g.

landingpage.html loads --> homepage.html

homepage.html loads --> homepage2.html

Comment: Doesn't look like there's a solution, awarding to Jin for his efforts :)

Answer (score 0):

(You might have solved your problem, still if below helps)

I am using RC2 now (just released) and they made big changes around this area in Beta3,
I am using normal links like:-

and it is working fine for me.
Though I also kept PushStateEnabled to True in header:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
          $(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {

              $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = true;
              $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = true;
          });
        </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).bind("mobileinit",
        function(){ 
            $.extend( $.mobile , { ajaxEnabled: false }); 
        }
    );
</script>
```

Add this script to the layout page (or wherever you have referenced the jQuery scripts.

This should solve the problem, however, it just disabled the ajax. This will require more research to find out how we overcome having  # in the url while still having ajax enabled.